# How is jQuery/$ both a function and a 'prototype root'

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

This is a difficult one to explain, so I welcome comments querying the details. Basically with jQuery you can do the following things:

.

### What I want

```
$.ajax().etc()
$("selector").doStuff().etc()
```

Which means that $ is acting as a function (that is then chainable) as well as an object (also chainable).

.

### What I've got

I am writing some javascript myself and have successfully made a chainable set of functions like so:

```
myF.func1().func2()
myF('text') //Cannot get this working!
```

.

I'm using `window.myF=(new myFuncs())` to get the first line working, but I can't then use myF as a function. I've also made it so that myF can be used as a function, but then I can't chain the other functions.

I'm extremely confused and as much as I've tried searching this site and Google, I must be searching the wrong thing as I have no idea where to go from here!

Questions in the comments are welcomed and expected!

.

### My Setup (simplified)

```
(function(){
    var myFuncs=function(){

    };

    myFuncs.prototype = {
          foo: function() {
          }
          ,bar: function() {
          }
    }

    window.myF = (new myFuncs());
})();
```

Comment: How about just doing `$.fn.myF = function(text) { ... };` if you're working with jQuery objects and wish to have it chainable ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I'm not actually working with jQuery - I'm just after the way it can be called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a quick look at the jQuery source code and it looks like it doesn't use prototypes for the jQuery object - the `window.$`.

Instead it uses `$.extend`:

```
var myF = function(){};
$.extend(myF, {
   actAsAnObject: function(){}
});
```

However, for what I'll call the jQuery response object it does use prototypes. So if you call `myF()` this code gets run:

```
var myF = function(){
    return new myF.prototype.init(arguments); // based on the jQuery code
};
```

`$.post` is an object property, you can't get it if you call the function itself. `$().html` is a jQuery response object function, it is not a member of the `window.$`object.

---

Answer to your update: http://jsfiddle.net/rmpW8/

```
(function(){
    var myFuncExternal = function(num){
        return new myFunc(num);           
    };
    var myFunc = function(num){
        this.num = num;
    };

    $.extend(myFuncExternal, {
        foo: function(num){
            console.log("In foo with: " + num);
        }
    })

    myFunc.prototype = {
          foo: function() {
              myFuncExternal.foo(this.num);
          },
          bar: function() {
              console.log("In bar with: " + this.num)
          }
    }

    window.myF = myFuncExternal;
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Just make your `myF` a function. The *static* methods on the jQuery object are just assigned to that function directly.

```
(function(exports) {

    exports.myF = function() {
        // This function can return an instance of itself, to make
        // it chainable.
    };

    exports.myF.staticFunction = function() {
        // This is a *static* function, available directly on `myF`
        // in the global space.
    };

})(this);
```

Comment: Right, okay, so I can't get this functionality as it is at the moment using `myF.prototype={ foo:func(), bar:func() }` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP That's the preferred method of adding methods on the prototype, yes. Keep in mind that will clobber any existing `prototype` property augmentations.

Comment: Okay, it's actually already set up to be a function - if you check out my updated post you can see what I've got.

Answer (score 2):

You'd do something like this:

```
myF = function () {
  ...
}
myF.method1 = function (){
  ...
}
myF.method2 = function (){
  ...
}
...
```

In Javascript, you have to remember that **ANY** data can have properties, even if it's not an "object", per se. So strings, numbers, functions, all of those can (and do) have properties. For example, strings have the property `length`.

Comment: So I'll just need to take it out of the prototype set I created? See my updated question with my setup. If i just change that to `myFuncs.foo = function()` etc that'll be it?

Comment: This is correct but it suggests that primitive values can be assigned own properties, which is not true.